# unset path in windows

Tags: windows, path

how can I remove enry from the PATH in windows, to set path I need to use `SET PATH command` but I can't find what do I need to do remove some entry from the path (UNSET PATH is not working), thanks in advance
P.S. from command line in windows

Comment: What language? What have you tried, and did you encounter specific problems with your efforts?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on superuser.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove an individual item from an environment variable. You have to read in the current value, parse it, remove what you want to remove, and then reset the variable.

If you aren't doing this in code then I can recommend [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com) as an excellent tool to make this work easy.

Comment: +1 very nice tool written in Delphi. ;)